# Should all badges be attainable?

Tags: discussion

I looked at [SO meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/should-the-beta-badges-stop-being-awarded-to-users), and they have removed the badge for participating in the beta.

I think that all the badges should be attainable for everyone, so badges like Beta and precognative.

I do understand that these are a medal and people are proud to ahve them but can these be incorporated into the profile rather than a badge, as no newer users will ever have the chance of gaining these badges.

Comment: Oooh, if we down vote the question and up vote the answer enough, will we get a "Reversal" here?

Comment: I'm all for it :-)

Comment: @Daniel Sounds like a good idea to me!

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of badges which are practically unattainable for various reasons:

- "participated in Beta" -> obvious
- "Legendary" (Earned 200 daily reputation 150 times) -> maybe in a few years
- "Reversal" (Provided answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score) -> how likely is that?

So I think one unattainable badge more or less doesn't matter.

Comment: These can ultimately be achieved over time. The ones i have mentioned are absolutely unattainable from now onwards, there is no point in having them.

Comment: So? Let the beta users have their badge, there are more than enough badges to go for remaining :-)

Comment: have the badge but why list it, if it cannot be achieved?

Comment: @GraemeHutchison, do you mean to list it on people's profiles, but not on the [list of badges](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/badges)?

Comment: @Daniel yes, either list it as a badge or as something else, on the profile, and remove it from the list of attainable badges.